# How to recover devastated packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, 20.04, dpkg

I wanted to install LMMS (An open-source music tool), used apt to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install lmms
```

However, it showed `these packages will be removed` text. It showed lots of packages actually.
Then I said eeeh whatever, at least thousands of people downloaded this way. But it really tried to remove everything I don't know why.

I have managed to stop it. But it deleted lots of packages.

This is the output from `cat /var/log/dpkg.log | grep remove`

```bsh
2020-12-27 12:50:41 startup packages remove
2020-12-27 12:50:41 remove albert:amd64 0.17.2-0 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:42 remove alsa-tools-gui:amd64 1.1.7-1ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:42 remove apport-gtk:all 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.8 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:43 remove nautilus-share:amd64 0.7.3-2ubuntu3 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:44 remove apturl:amd64 0.5.2ubuntu19 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:45 remove ubuntu-desktop:amd64 1.450.2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:46 remove ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 1.450.2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:46 remove orca:all 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:48 remove python3-pyatspi:all 2.36.0-1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:48 remove at-spi2-core:amd64 2.36.0-2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:49 remove baobab:amd64 3.34.0-1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:50 remove brltty:amd64 6.0+dfsg-4ubuntu6 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:53 remove cheese:amd64 3.34.0-1build1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:54 remove chrome-gnome-shell:all 10.1-5 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:54 remove gdm3:amd64 3.34.1-1ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:56 remove ubuntu-session:all 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:56 remove gnome-startup-applications:amd64 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:57 remove gnome-session-bin:amd64 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:58 remove shotwell:amd64 0.30.10-0ubuntu0.1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:58 remove nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal:amd64 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04 <none>
2020-12-27 12:50:59 remove xorg:amd64 1:7.7+19ubuntu14 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:00 remove gnome-terminal:amd64 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:00 remove dbus-x11:amd64 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:01 remove dconf-editor:amd64 3.36.0-1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:02 remove deja-dup:amd64 40.7-0ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:03 remove eog:amd64 3.36.3-0ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:05 remove evince:amd64 3.36.7-0ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:06 remove update-notifier:amd64 3.192.30 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:07 remove update-manager:all 1:20.04.10.1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:51:08 remove ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all 1:20.04.25 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:25 startup packages remove
2020-12-27 12:54:25 remove apturl-common:amd64 0.5.2ubuntu19 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:26 remove duplicity:amd64 0.8.11.1612-1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:27 remove evince-common:all 3.36.7-0ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:28 remove libpam-fprintd:amd64 1.90.1-1ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:29 remove fprintd:amd64 1.90.1-1ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:30 remove gnome-session-common:all 3.36.0-2ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:31 remove gnome-terminal-data:all 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:33 remove libfprint-2-2:amd64 1:1.90.2+tod1-0ubuntu1~20.04.1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:34 remove libglu1-mesa:amd64 9.0.1-1build1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:35 remove libmuparser2v5:amd64 2.2.6.1+dfsg-1build1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:35 remove libpcre2-32-0:amd64 10.34-7 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:36 remove libqt5concurrent5:amd64 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:37 remove libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:37 remove libqt5sql5:amd64 5.12.8+dfsg-0ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:38 remove libraw19:amd64 0.19.5-1ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:39 remove librsync2:amd64 2.0.2-1ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:39 remove python3-paramiko:all 2.6.0-2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:40 remove python3-bcrypt:amd64 3.1.7-2ubuntu1 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:41 remove python3-brlapi:amd64 6.0+dfsg-4ubuntu6 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:42 remove python3-fasteners:all 0.14.1-2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:43 remove python3-future:all 0.18.2-2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:43 remove python3-lockfile:all 1:0.12.2-2ubuntu2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:44 remove python3-louis:all 3.12.0-3 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:45 remove python3-monotonic:all 1.5-0ubuntu2 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:46 remove python3-speechd:all 0.9.1-4 <none>
2020-12-27 12:54:47 remove shotwell-common:all 0.30.10-0ubuntu0.1 <none>
```

I don't know how to recover from here. I thought about manually re-install everything using, `aptitude install` but no luck from there too.

```
  ~ sudo aptitude install nautilus-share                  
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apturl{a} apturl-common{a} dbus-x11{ab} gnome-session-bin{a} gnome-session-common{a} gnome-startup-applications{a} nautilus-share 
0 packages upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 215 kB of archives. After unpacking 1.415 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dbus-x11 : Depends: libdbus-1-3 (= 1.12.16-2ubuntu2) but 1.12.16-2ubuntu2.1 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     dbus-x11 [Not Installed]                           
2)     gnome-session-bin [Not Installed]                  
3)     gnome-startup-applications [Not Installed]         
4)     nautilus-share [Not Installed]                     



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is really strange and definitely shouldn't happen. Reinstalling the ubuntu-desktop package should at least get you back all packages installed by default. (Assuming you're using vanilla Ubuntu.) To do so execute `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install --fix-broken` could also come in handy.

Good luck salvaging the system!

Comment: Eeeeh, I tried these, they didn't work though.  I opened another tty copied my entire home directory to a hard drive, got everything moved to the Arch. Anyway, thank you!